# Как вывести вот такое уведомление на Android

Tags: java, android

Нужно вывести вот такое уведомление на android на java http://m.imgur.com/V6aIHnL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
        super.onDestroy();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Нажмите еще раз для выхода", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```